# NSCountedSet Duplicates and count in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsset

I have a `NSSet` method checking for duplicates and the count of duplicates of each name. I want to place the names in the table view with the number of duplicates with it. I have taken 100 names and return 27 cells after I find duplicates but I can not seem to get the number of duplicates to be placed in the table view with the corresponding names. Here is a screen shot and method I have been trying to work with to get this working.

[image]

```
- (NSSet *)checkForDuplicateIDs {

//CHECK FOR DUPLICATES IN ARRAY
NSArray *allIDs = [tweetArray valueForKeyPath:@"sender_screen_name"];
NSArray *sortedIDs = [allIDs sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

NSString *previousID = nil;
duplicateIDs = [NSMutableSet set];
for (NSString *anID in sortedIDs) {
    if ([previousID isEqualToString:anID]) {
        [duplicateIDs addObject:anID];

    }
    previousID = anID;
}


//THEN REMOVE ANY DUPLICATES IN NEW ARRAY
NSCountedSet *countedSet = [NSCountedSet setWithArray:sortedIDs];
NSMutableArray *oneMess = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[sortedIDs count]];
NSMutableArray *multipleMess = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[sortedIDs count]];


for(id obj in countedSet) {
    if([countedSet countForObject:obj] == 1) {
        [oneMess addObject:obj];
    }
    for(id duplicatenames in countedSet) {
        if ([countedSet countForObject:duplicatenames]>1) {
            [multipleMess addObject:duplicatenames];
            [countedSet  countForObject:duplicatenames];

        }


    }


}


//other method.... much easier and cleaner but how do I put them into an array?
NSCountedSet *set = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:allIDs];

for (id item in set)
{
  //  NSLog(@"Name=%@, Count=%lu", item, (unsigned long)[set countForObject:item]);
}    





//  NSLog(@"NSCountedSet ALL Objects = %@",[countedSet allObjects]);
//  NSLog(@"NSCountedSet = %@",countedSet);

[tweetArray removeAllObjects];
[tweetArray addObjectsFromArray:[countedSet allObjects]];
tweetArrayCount = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:countedSet, nil];


//NSLog(@"One Message = %@",oneMess);
// NSLog(@"Multiple Messages = %@",multipleMess);


//HERE I HAVE ORIGINAL ARRAY IN ALBETICAL ORDER
// NSLog(@"Messages Containing more then 1 = %@",sortedIDs);    

//HERE I HAVE DUPLICATES IN ALBETICAL ORDER
// NSLog(@"Messages Containing more then 1 = %@",duplicateIDs);

//HERE I HAVE THE MESSAGES ONLY CONTAING 1
//NSLog(@"Messages Containing only 1 = %@",oneMess);


//NSLog(@"Duplicates count = %i",[duplicateIDs count]);
// NSLog(@"Messages Containing only count = %i",[oneMess count]);



[mainTableView reloadData];


return [[duplicateIDs copy] autorelease];

}
```

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is -- none of the posted code shows how you tried to get the count into the table.  How are you trying to do that?  Where in the table do you want the number to go? The counted set method is certainly the way to go to get a unique set along with a count of each object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified a simple UITableView example that lists country names to do what I think you want to do.  The count is put in the detailTextLabel.text.

```
countedList = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:listOfItems];//listOfItems is an array of country name strings with duplicates
    listOfItems2 = [NSMutableArray array]; // array without duplicates that's the data source for the UITableView

    for (NSString *aCountry in countedList) {
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [dict setValue:aCountry forKey:@"name"];
        [dict setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",[countedList countForObject:aCountry]] forKey:@"count"];
        [listOfItems2 addObject:dict];
    }
```

And then I used the following method to supply the data for the table:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; //
    }

    // Set up the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [[listOfItems2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"name"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[listOfItems2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"count"];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking to accomplish...By giving the valueForKey it allows a string at the table view which I kept putting arrays or sets there and crashing of course. Very much appreciated!